# Rotating Rectangle() In SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

```
Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.blue)
        .frame(width: 1000, height: randomPOS(true, false))
```

Hey so Im trying to rotate this rectangle and .rotationeffect() isn't working does anyone know how you would go about doing this I wasn't able to find anything on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`rotationEffect(_:anchor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/rotationeffect(_:anchor:)) modifier.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(45))
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Nice code for part of `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` Instant square!